# Javascript regular expression for tv episodes

Tags: javascript, regex

What I'm trying to do is match the season and episode numbers from these different possible combinations:

```
S01E05
S1E5
1x05
1x5
```

Where the data im interested in is season number 1 and episode number 5 from each.

Comment: This is not a bad question, but [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following expression, which will capture series and episode number without the leading zero:

```
^S?0*(\d+)?[xE]0*(\d+)
```

At the moment, the detection is anchored to the start of the name with the `^` char. Remove it, if the series name is somewhere else in the string.

Comment: Ok, edited it to allow for more than 0 zero and matching correctly.

Comment: This is probably as good as its going to get without making the expression unnecessarily complex. Here's an explanation and demo: http://regex101.com/r/mW8gE4

I suggest you add a anchor (`$`) to the end, too.

Comment: @chiborg I need to support capital E and small e for episodes and same for season too

Answer (score 0):

This should match all of your examples with multi-line modifier enabled:

```
^S?\d+[Ex]\d+$
```

The downside is that it will also match:

```
S01x5
```

If this is not acceptable, you'll need a variation of the above regex to detect whether or not the input started with `S`.